# How Can I Query LDAP for All Users By Filter in Grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

The grails application I'm working on has a requirement to allow users to select a user from a list. However, the users in this list may not have logged-in previously.

Since the selection of users is not complete, I wish to query LDAP for users by granted authorities. The problem is that I can't find the reference material in either documentation of API docs to help me figure it out.

Is there an API method in SpringSource Security that will allow me to perform searches? How can I search for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use `gldapo` lib to get information from `ldap` directories:

http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2009/02/10/configuration-and-usage-of-gldapo-in-a-grails-project

http://gldapo.codehaus.org/